# Bargain Finder Max Rest API v4

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, sabre, sabredav

I am trying to implement **Bargain Finder Max** Rest API in the Node js application. But It returns this type of data. So could you please tell me how can I get complete useful data? The JSON is too large so I am sharing JSON files by uploading. I will be grateful for your kind help. Thanks in Advance

**I am using Bargain Finder Max v4.**

https://github.com/SyedHasibRahman/flight-search-jsons/blob/main/Sabre-search-flight.json

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
What have you tried? What were the results?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the issue with the response, the size of the response, depends of the quantity of solutions and complexity of itineraries you want to return during the service call as "flexibility, brands, legs, mct", so, my suggestion is to create a middle-tier service to handle requests, so, your frontend application would then make the request to this middle-tier service, which would then call the Sabre API, this way you can serialize the responses as desired and by doing this, you will be able to decouple your frontend, so in case of changes to the Sabre API in future versions you can maintain with less difficulty.